# SQL - sequencing column data in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have a table with 3 fields:

```
CUST_ORDER  FULFILL_NO  ITEM  LOCATION
   SA23        1        0233    11001
   SA23        1        0243    13001
   SA23        1        0513    14001
   SA88        1        0873    15001
   SA88        1        0533    17001
```

I want to sequence the fulfill_no field so that data becomes:

```
CUST_ORDER  FULFILL_NO  ITEM  LOCATION
   SA23        1        0233    11001
   SA23        2        0243    13001
   SA23        3        0513    14001
   SA88        1        0873    15001
   SA88        2        0533    17001
```

How to do that ?

Comment: is there an order you have to follow? it is inconsistent in the sample data.

Comment: not in any order. just sequence according to CUST_ORDER

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select cust_order,
       row_number() over (partition by cust_order order by location) as fulfill_no,
       item, location
from t;
```

Actually updating the data can be tricky in Oracle.  Here is one way:

```
update t
    set fulfill_no = (select count(*)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.cust_order = t.cust_order and t2.location <= t.location
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Gordon Linoff's answer. I'd like to point out that Gordon's row_number() solution works in Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, and PostgreSQL. This answer probably works for the questioner, given the oracle tag on the question.

If a MySQL user finds this question and needs a solution, they should use a session variable instead. Implementing row_number() in MySQL was asked on stackoverflow already: [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)
I'm sorry I don't have MySQL available to test with, but to try my hand at customizing the above query to MySQL...

```
SELECT
   t.CUST_ORDER,
   (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS FULFILL_NO,
   t.ITEM,
   t.LOCATION
FROM YOUR_TABLE t,
   (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY t.CUST_ORDER, t.LOCATION
```

For more advanced usage, you could try this link.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/